# Create Zoho campaign with api gives error

Tags: api, zoho

I tried to create a zoho campaign following this link https://www.zoho.com/campaigns/help/api/create-campaign.html

but every time, I get an error 1004
according to https://www.zoho.com/campaigns/help/api/error-codes.html , 1004 gives Wrong URL entered.

This is the link that I used

https://campaigns.zoho.com/api/v2/createcampaign?campaignName=mynewone&from_email=sammoudi.maher@gmail.com&subject=testSubject&authtoken=6fd68951538f7489e2406ac6f5a59bbe&resfmt=json

Where is the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

the url is case sensitive. I think the url you are using should be https://campaigns.zoho.com/api/v2/createCampaign? (note the capital "C" at the end)

you may also want to change your api key since you posted it for the world to see :)